# using implode with date in php

Tags: php, mysql

In a simple sales app i'm saving login time/ date for every employee like this

```
$update= mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE employees set loggedin= now() WHERE email = '$email'");
```

`loggedin` field is of  `DATETIME` type, and this is how i get values in  it for every login

**2015-12-20 19:15:08**

now i've to store one login per day so if for today there already exists a value i will not update login  this is what i'm trying to do

```
$time= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT loggedin  from employees WHERE email  = '$email'");
$loggedin_time= mysqli_fetch_assoc($time);
$loggedin_time_converted= implode("  ",$loggedin_time) ;
```

and after imploding i want to check if   today's date has already got a login  time but this is not working for me  how do i separate date / time so that i can use it separately  for later checks

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: if you went through the whole question  " how do i saperate date / time so that i can use it separately for later chceks"

Comment: Then start with understanding that `implode` - glues pieces together. while `EXPLODE` does what you need.

Comment: Also understand that `$loggedin_time= mysqli_fetch_assoc($time);` will return an array into `$loggedin_time` so that `loggedin` will be in `$loggedin_time['loggedin']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `loggedin_time` is an associate array, you need to define the key , `$loggedin_time['yourDateColumn']`. Then you can start separating the date and time, note that use `explode` instead.

```
$loggedin_time= mysqli_fetch_assoc($time);;
$yourDateTime = $loggedin_time['yourDateColumn'];
$loggedin_time_converted= explode(" ",$yourDateTime) ;// only one space in " " , you're using two.
```

and the result :

```
$yourDate = $loggedin_time_converted[0]; // Date
$yourTime =  $loggedin_time_converted[1]; // Time
```

Comment: so if i've to store it in a session that does not allow me to store array what should i do then

Comment: Because you didn't read my answer correclty, did you?, `$yourDate` & `$yourTime`, they are strings, I mentioned that i'm using `explode`, and watch out that you're using double space in `" "`. And sorry I just edited my answer, I wrongly pass the `$yourDate` var to `$loggedin_time_converted`.

Comment: this is what it says  Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: Hmm.. i didn't see anything wrong in my answer. Could you try to change it to `$loggedin_time_converted= explode(" ",$yourDate[0]) ;`

Comment: Perfect now it worked for me , Thanks man.. i spent 2 hours working with this  and finally you helped me to fix this .

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead of the last two lines, something like

```
$logged_in_today = false;
while ($row = $time->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (strpos($row['loggedin'],date('Y-m-d')) !== false) {
        $logged_in_today = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to include the date you want to check for an already existing entry in the query (in your case it always seems to be today).

Hence:

```
SELECT loggedin  from employees 
WHERE email  = '$email'
AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(loggedin, '%Y%m%d')
```

This way, whenever you get a match with this query (e.g. just count the rows), then there is already an entry for today. If you get no matches, there is no entry for today for that employee.

If you want to check for a different date, just exchange the `CURDATE()` with that, et voila!